How to get an auto-incremented ID from my DAO?
I'm having some trouble with auto-incremented columns in my Java application (using H2). Mainly, I cannot figure out the best way to access the ID from my DAO:
The relevant sections of code are:
I have a table PEOPLE with my auto-incremented ID column and the String NAME column:
create table PEOPLE (
    ID INTEGER auto_increment,
    NAME CHARACTER VARYING(50)
);


PeopleDAO.java
public class PeopleDAO {
    public static ObservableList<People> getPeople() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM PEOPLE";
        try {
            PreparedStatement statement = getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = DBHelpers.executeQuerry(statement);
            return getPeopleList(rs);
        } catch (SQLException e {
            throw e
        }
    }

    public static ObservableList<Person> getPeopleList(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ObservableList<Person> peopleList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        while (rs.next()) {
             Person person = new Person(
                  rs.getString("NAME");
             peopleList.add(person);
        }
        return peopleList;
    }

    public static void insertPerson(String name) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO PEOPLE (NAME) VALUES (?)";
        try {
             PreparedStatement statement = getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
             statement.setString(1, name);
             DBHelpers.executeUpdate(statement);
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
             throw e;
        }
   }
}

DBHelpers.java
This has my driver, URL, connection etc. getConnection() returns the Connection object, and executeQuery() and exeucteUpdate() do what they say they do (statement.executeQuery() and statement.executeUpdate() respectively)
Person.java
public class Person {
    String name;
    
    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

My question is how do I access the ID column from a Person object? I tried adding the field
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
int ID;

to Person, and making a getter for it, but it returns 0, not 1, for the first object, which I think has to do with it being a zero-indexed list of objects. If it were a non-incrementing column I would just add ID when I create Person objects in getPeopleList(), but with the IDs being auto-assigned I'm not sure how to do this.
I can post more of my code if necessary.

Your last code snippet indicates you are using some kind of database ORM mapper. You need to indicate what mapper you are using, such as Spring Data or Jakarta Persistence. Add a tag at least, and ideally a mention as well. If you want a straight-JDBC solution, say so.

I'm not using a mapper, I just thought I would try to see what it did (it did not work). I would like a straight JDBC solution unless using a mapper is significantly better overall.

The pros and cons of using  a mapper framework is debatable. But I suspect many folks would recommending understanding the basics of straight JDBC first, so you have a sense of what such tools are doing.

tl;dr
You are asking how to access from Java via JDBC the key generated within the database engine while inserting a row into a table.
To do that, instruct the PreparedStatement to return any generated keys by passing an optional argument of Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS while preparing the statement in a call to Connection#prepareStatement.
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement( sql , Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS ) ;

Then loop the ResultSet of generated keys.
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys( ) ;

Details
First get the basics of your app working, with dummy data and no database.
Let's define the Person class, with both fields, id & name.
If the primary purpose of your class is to transparently communicate shallowly-immutable data, define the class as a record.
public record Person( int id , String name ) { }

Let's use the common Repository pattern. We define an interface defining methods for storing and retrieving objects.
public interface Repository
{
    public Collection < Person > allPeople ( );

    public Optional < Person > addPerson ( String name );
}

Make a bogus implementation, just to get our first few parts in working order.
public class RepositoryBogus implements Repository
{
    private Collection < Person > persons =
            new ArrayList <>(
                    List.of(
                            new Person( 1 , "Alice" ) ,
                            new Person( 2 , "Bob" ) ,
                            new Person( 3 , "Carol" )
                    ) );

    @Override
    public List < Person > allPeople ( )
    {
        return List.copyOf( this.persons );
    }

    @Override
    public Optional < Person > addPerson ( final String name )
    {
        Person person = new Person( ( this.persons.size( ) + 1 ) , name );
        this.persons.add( person );
        return Optional.of( person );
    }
}

Write an app to exercise these classes.
public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App( );
        app.demo( );
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        Repository repository = new RepositoryBogus( );

        // Before
        Collection < Person > persons = repository.allPeople( );
        System.out.println( "persons = " + persons );

        // After
        Optional < Person > optionalDavis = repository.addPerson( "Davis" );
        System.out.println( "optionalDavis = " + optionalDavis );  // Verify that Davis got an id value.
        System.out.println( "repository.allPeople() = " + repository.allPeople( ) );  // Verify that Davis and his id were stored in database successfully.
    }
}

Our addPerson method returns an Optional in case of failure. We must test the Optional to verify success.
When run, we see success. We adding “Davis” as our 4th person, getting back an object whose id field has a value 4 as expected.
persons = [Person[id=1, name=Alice], Person[id=2, name=Bob], Person[id=3, name=Carol]]
optionalDavis = Optional[Person[id=4, name=Davis]]
repository.allPeople() = [Person[id=1, name=Alice], Person[id=2, name=Bob], Person[id=3, name=Carol], Person[id=4, name=Davis]]

Now we can implement a proper implementation of Repository to work with an H2 Database Engine database.
Our initial implementation is minimal:
public class RepositoryH2 implements Repository
{
    @Override
    public Collection < Person > allPeople ( )
    {
        return List.of( );
    }

    @Override
    public Optional < Person > addPerson ( final String name )
    {
        return Optional.empty( );
    }
}

Run our same app code again.
persons = []
optionalDavis = Optional.empty
repository.allPeople() = []

Good, as expected.
We need DataSource implementation to hold our database credentials (username, password, server address, database product-specific settings, etc.). In real work we would obtain one through JNDI from a naming/directory server. In our example here, we fake it hard-coding values in an object of the simple implementation bundled with H2: org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.
We need to create a table in the database, then populate it. In real work, we would use a database migration tool such as Flyway or Liquibase. In our example here, we fake it by hard-coding some SQL in JDBC code.
We do both the DataSource instantiation and the table creation/population in some static methods on a class named DatabaseUtils. We also write a method to dump the table to console for debugging.
The critical part of creating the table is using a feature relatively new to the SQL standard: Identity columns. H2 supports the convenient new syntax to declare that the database engine automatically increment a column on a table:

GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY

In the past when lacking such a standard, database engines like H2 and Postgres each implemented such a feature in their own way with their own syntax. Such products have been moving to support the standard syntax, fortunately for us. See the H2 documentation on column definition.
Here is the code for creating & populating the table, while returning a DataSource object for us to use later when instantiating our Repository implementation.
package work.basil.example.db.autoincrement;

import org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource;
import org.intellij.lang.annotations.Language;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.List;

// The code here is a hack to keep our example simple.
// In real work you would obtain a `DataSource` object via JNDI from a naming/directory server.
// In real work you would create tables by way of a database migration tool such as Flyway or Liquibase.
public class DatabaseUtils
{
    public static DataSource makeDatabase ( )
    {
        DataSource dataSource = DatabaseUtils.fetchDataSource( );
        DatabaseUtils.createPersonTable( dataSource );
        DatabaseUtils.populatePersonTable( dataSource );
        DatabaseUtils.dumpPersonTable( dataSource );
        return dataSource;
    }

    private static DataSource fetchDataSource ( )
    {
        JdbcDataSource dataSource = new JdbcDataSource( );  // Implementation of `DataSource` bundled with H2.
        dataSource.setURL( "jdbc:h2:mem:h2_identity_example_db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" ); // Set `DB_CLOSE_DELAY` to `-1` to keep in-memory database in existence after connection closes.
        dataSource.setUser( "scott" );
        dataSource.setPassword( "tiger" );
        return dataSource;
    }

    private static void createPersonTable ( final DataSource dataSource )
    {
        @Language ( "SQL" )
        String sql = """
                CREATE TABLE person_
                   ( 
                      id_ INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,  -- ⬅ `identity` = auto-incrementing integer number.
                      name_ VARCHAR NOT NULL 
                    )
                ;
                """;
        try (
                Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection( ) ;
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement( ) ;
        )
        {
            statement.execute( sql );
        } catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
    }

    private static void populatePersonTable ( final DataSource dataSource )
    {
        @Language ( "SQL" )
        String sql = """
                INSERT INTO person_ (  name_ )
                VALUES ( ? )
                ;
                """;
        try (
                Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection( ) ;
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
        )
        {
            for ( String name : List.of( "Alice" , "Bob" , "Carol" ) )
            {
                preparedStatement.setString( 1 , name );
                int rowCount = preparedStatement.executeUpdate( );
                if ( rowCount != 1 ) throw new IllegalStateException( "Failed to insert " + name + " into database" );
            }
        } catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
    }

    public static void dumpPersonTable ( final DataSource dataSource )
    {
        @Language ( "SQL" )
        String sql = """
                SELECT *
                FROM person_
                ;
                """;
        try (
                Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection( ) ;
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement( ) ;
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery( sql ) ;
        )
        {
            System.out.println( "---------|  Start dump of table person_  |--------------------" );
            while ( resultSet.next( ) )
            {
                System.out.println( new Person( resultSet.getInt( "id_" ) , resultSet.getString( "name_" ) ) );
            }
            System.out.println( "---------|  End dump of table person_  |--------------------" );
        } catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
    }
}

So with a DataSource in hand, and a database table in place, we can flesh out our Repository implementation.
The allPeople method is basically the same as the dumpPersonTable method seen above.
The addPerson method gets at the heart of your Question: How to access from Java via JDBC the key generated within the database engine. To make that happen, ask the PreparedStatement to return any generated keys back to Java. Do that by passing an optional argument of Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS while preparing the statement with a call to Connection#prepareStatement.
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement( sql , Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS ) ;

So here is our RepositoryH2 class, implementing our Repository interface.
package work.basil.example.db.autoincrement;

import org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource;
import org.intellij.lang.annotations.Language;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class RepositoryH2 implements Repository
{
    // Member fields
    private final DataSource dataSource;

    // Constructors
    public RepositoryH2 ( final DataSource dataSource )
    {
        this.dataSource = Objects.requireNonNull( dataSource );
    }


    //------------|  Implement Repository  |-----------------------------------

    @Override
    public Collection < Person > allPeople ( )
    {
        @Language ( "SQL" )
        String sql = """
                SELECT *
                FROM person_
                ;
                """;
        try (
                Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection( ) ;
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement( ) ;
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery( sql ) ;
        )
        {
            Collection < Person > persons = new ArrayList <>( );
            while ( resultSet.next( ) )
            {
                Person person = new Person( resultSet.getInt( "id_" ) , resultSet.getString( "name_" ) );
                persons.add( person );
            }
            return persons;
        } catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Optional < Person > addPerson ( final String name )
    {
        @Language ( "SQL" )
        String sql = """
                INSERT INTO person_ (  name_ )
                VALUES ( ? )
                ;
                """;

        Optional < Person > personOptional = Optional.empty( );
        try (
                Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection( ) ;
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement( sql , Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS ) ;
        )
        {
            preparedStatement.setString( 1 , name );

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate( );
            try (
                    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys( ) ;
            )
            {
                while ( rs.next( ) )
                {
                    int id = rs.getInt( 1 ); // Generated key.
                    Person person = new Person( id , name );
                    personOptional = Optional.of( person );
                }
            }
        } catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
        return personOptional;
    }
}

To exercise all this code, alter our App class’ demo method to establish the database before going on to run the demonstration.
DataSource dataSource = DatabaseUtils.makeDatabase( );
Repository repository = new RepositoryH2( dataSource );  //new RepositoryBogus( );

Voilà, we get the same results as we did with our bogus data.
persons = [Person[id=1, name=Alice], Person[id=2, name=Bob], Person[id=3, name=Carol]]
optionalDavis = Optional[Person[id=4, name=Davis]]
repository.allPeople() = [Person[id=1, name=Alice], Person[id=2, name=Bob], Person[id=3, name=Carol], Person[id=4, name=Davis]]

For more discussion, see my Answer to a similar Question.
